# Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.concat'

Tags: babeljs, webpack-4, babel-loader, react-styleguidist

I upgraded babel `6.x → 7.x` but having issues running *Webpack*.

It is complaining about missing `core-js/modules/*`.

My `babel.config.js` is in the root directory. I converted the previously existing `.babelrc` to js (`.babelrc` also produced the same errors). I am guessing it is some collision with all the core, `corejs2`, runtime stuff.

There are two apps in my src, mine and Styleguidist (in `./node_modules`). My app transpiles and works with these same *package.json/babel.config*, but Styleguidist does not.

---

The error when running Styleguidist with webpack:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.concat' in '/project/src/node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/rsg-components/Slot'
```

`/node_modules/react-styleguidist/lib/client/rsg-components/Slot.js`:

```
import "core-js/modules/es.array.concat";
import "core-js/modules/es.array.filter";
...
```

#### package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.4.3",
}
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx": "^7.3.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.3",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-helper-vue-jsx-merge-props": "^2.0.3",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^4.0.1",
}
```

#### babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
    plugins: [
        '@babel/plugin-transform-runtime',
        '@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx',
        'transform-vue-jsx',
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings",
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
            {
                "legacy": true
            }
        ],
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions"],
    comments: false
}
```

Comment: I looked at Styleguidist' package.json and saw that they have "core-js": "^3.0.0". I added that to my package.json and now it starts up!! Thanks, me. If someone can explain to me the reason for 15 different corejs's and polyfills, I would appreciate that.

Comment: 2 apps are working, but Jest does not.

Answer (score 23):

Quoting from `Babel 7.4.0` [release](https://babeljs.io/blog/2019/03/19/7.4.0) :

> @babel/polyfill isn't a plugin or preset, but a runtime package: if we added an option to switch between core-js@2 and core-js@3, both the package versions would need to be included in your bundle. For this reason, we decided to deprecate it: you now should load core-js for polyfills, and regenerator-runtime/runtime if you are transforming generators:

As you are using `7.4.3` version of babel, `@babel/polyfill` might not work as expected. Instead please add `core-js` and `regenerator-runtime` manually. Quoting from `core-js3` release [announcement](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/docs/2019-03-19-core-js-3-babel-and-a-look-into-the-future.md#babelpolyfill):

```
Instead of

import "@babel/polyfill";

you should use those 2 lines:

import "core-js/stable";
import "regenerator-runtime/runtime";

Don't forget install those dependencies directly!

npm i --save core-js regenerator-runtime
```

Comment: This answer has saved my day.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed.

Comment: His code didn't  direct import core-js, so this should be incorrect way to fix the problem (even if it can). The problem is he should use & set core-js 3 in babelrc explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue and as often happens I forgot to have another package installed as:

"@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.5.5",

Don't forgot to install it at same level where you have the issue(either dev, local or production) level:

```
 npm i -D(or --save-dev) @babel/runtime-corejs3
```

So in general this kind of errors happens when there are dependencies update  change significantly in the version and aren't backward compatible with previous versions(API changes). Indeed corejs3 isn't at all compatible with corejs2 or older.

Comment: Thanks. I just forget to install `npm install core-js@3 --save` when I tried to set `"corejs": "3.21.1"`  for the `@babel/preset-env` preset inside `babel.config.json`

Answer (score 1):

I found possible answer. 
To resolve this error, you can downgrade the core-js version to 2.5.7. This version produces correct catalogs structure, with separate ES6 and ES7 folders.

To downgrade the version, simply run:

npm i -S core-js@2.5.7

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find out whether the error complained about **corejs3** or **corejs2** and that is easy, if the error said something like `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es6.array.fill` then it is **corejs2**; if the error said something like `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/modules/es.array.concat'` then it is **corejs3**. That is because as the corejs author explained at [core-js@3, babel and a look into the future](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/blob/master/docs/2019-03-19-core-js-3-babel-and-a-look-into-the-future.md#packages-entry-points-and-modules-names)

> In previous versions of core-js, modules with polyfills for stable
> ECMAScript features and ECMAScript proposals were prefixed with **es6.**
> and **es7.**

So you need corejs3 and your `@babel/runtime-corejs2": "^7.4.3"` was wrong(that was why you get the error). From my experience babel 7 works best with corejs3.

Second, The core-js author said [it's 3 different ways of core-js usage. You should use only one of them](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/issues/848):

1. core-js direct import
2. core-js injecting by usage plugin from @babel/preset-env
3. core-js injecting without global pollution by @babel/transform-runtime plugin

You don't need to directly import corejs in your codes (as one answer suggetsed). The 2nd/3rd option is easier. I never directly import corejs in my codes. To use 2nd option using `useBuiltIns`. The babel document explains about the `useBuiltIns` option in [preset-env](https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-preset-env#usebuiltins-entry).

The babel document explains the 3rd option in https://babeljs.io/docs/babel-plugin-transform-runtime#options

The different between 2nd/3rd option lies in the difference between **core-js** and **core-js-pure**.  As the author said it in the core-js 3 [release note](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js/pull/325),

> Extract a version without global namespace pollution to a separate
> core-js-pure package (replacement for core-js/library).

If you use 3rd option then `npm install --save @babel/runtime-corejs3` instead of `npm i core-js`(which is for the 2nd option)

Answer (score 0):

So if you're using webpack with babelrc then it by default uses `corejs v2`, but you might have installed the latest version of `corejs` which is `v3`. So this error pops up to you.

Solution:

**If you want latest corejs support:**

1. Go to `webpack.config.js`
   under `module` where you have written presets,
   update it to:

```
presets: [[
  "@babel/preset-env",
  {
    corejs: "3",
    useBuiltIns: "usage"
  }
], "...otherPresets, if you have any"]
```

2. make the same change in `.babelrc`

```
"presets": [
  [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "corejs": "3",
      "useBuiltIns": "usage",
      "debug": false
    }
  ],
  "...otherPresets, if you have any"
]
```

**If you don't want to make the above changes** (which you shouldn't)
do:

```bash
npm i core-js@2.6.11 # install latest subversion in the corejs2
```